How to build rust rdkafka for x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
I'm having the same problem on building an app that depends on rdkafka on Alpine stated on this question
Caesar suggestion fixed the build errors but when running the binary on Alpine, I get a:
exec /home/app/rkc: no such file or directory

Here's the Dockerfile im using:
FROM clux/muslrust:latest AS chef

RUN cargo install cargo-chef --locked
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/musl-gcc /usr/bin/musl-g++
WORKDIR /home/app

FROM chef AS planner
COPY platforms/rkc/. platforms/rkc/.

WORKDIR /home/app/platforms/rkc
RUN cargo chef prepare

FROM chef AS builder 
COPY --from=planner /home/app/platforms/rkc/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release

# copy project files
COPY platforms/rkc/. platforms/rkc/.
RUN cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

FROM alpine as final
COPY --from=builder /home/app/platforms/rkc/target/release/rkc /home/app/rkc
CMD ["/home/app/rkc"]

I understand that no such file or directory means that there was something linked library that wasn't found.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!
To be able to run rdkafka in alpine.
